# Cannot connect to influxd by influx CLI tool

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

I installed influx in my CentOS 8.2 Server.

```
[root@dele opt]# influxd version
InfluxDB 2.0.2 (git: 84496e507a) build_date: 2020-11-19T03:59:35Z
[root@dele opt]# influx version
Influx CLI 2.0.2 (git: 84496e507a) build_date: 2020-11-19T03:59:35Z
```

I started influxd:

```
influxd &
```

there it LISTEN on 8086.

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8086                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

but I cannot connect to influxd:

```
[root@fastnetmon opt]# influx -host localhost -p 8086
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'o' in -ost
See 'influx -h' for help
[root@fastnetmon opt]# influx --host localhost --p 8086
Error: unknown flag: --host
See 'influx -h' for help
```

nor by command:

```
[root@dele opt]# /usr/bin/influx -precision rfc3339
Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'p' in -precision
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for sometime, I verified that these commands are not supported by 2.0 version.
In case of 2.0 version, you can perform queries in the influxdb in the "Data Explorer section". In 2.0 version, you have buckets similarly to databases and you can create them from cli as below example :

```
influx bucket create -n <bucketname> --org-id <Organisation ID> -r 10h -t <your token>
```

Token are generated from the homepage of the influxdb and you can access every part of your InfluxDB 2.0 instance from this homepage .
 You can access your organizations, dashboards, and documentation from here.